# Laravel Http::fake response with file

Tags: file, testing, phpunit, laravel-8, response

I am trying to mock/test an `Http` request in a feature test to mock the whatsapp APIs, using Http::fake() in the setUp as follow:

```
        Http::fake([
            'https://www.test-whatsapp.com/upload/image' => Http::response(UploadedFile::fake()->image('TestWhatsapp.jpg')->get()),
            'https://www.test-whatsapp.com/*' => Http::response(),
        ]);
```

I'd like to mock that when my app calls https://www.test-whatsapp.com/upload/image i get the file content but it seems that it never get sent. This is my actual test:

```
    public function test_ask_attachment_image()
    {
        $this->receivedMessage(['type' => 'TEXT', 'text' => 'ask-attachment']);
        $this->receivedMessage(['type' => 'IMAGE', 'caption' => 'some text', 'url' => '"https://www.test-whatsapp.com/upload/image']);
        Http::assertSent(function (Request $request){
            Log::debug($request->url(), [$request->body()]);
            return true;
        });
    }
```

But the log gives an empty body.

I tried to `print_r` the whole response but still no sign of the file.

In the end I tried with an existing file using `file_get_content` but i got the same result.

I have logged the faked file and it get the content right.

How can i fake an endpoint to return me a file content? Thank you for any suggestions!

**Edit**

After debugging more i found out that the problem is not when i'm trying to create an image but a generic file using the method `UploadedFile::fake()->create('TestWhatsapp.mp4', 1000)`. I get the size and the mimetype right but the file is still empty.

Comment: did you try `Http::response([UploadedFile::fake()->image('TestWhatsapp.jpg')->get()])`?